# Java Derby DB - Column (PrimaryKey) with "Generated Always as Identity " adding up 100 to the base number everytime application restart

Tags: java, derby

I am having problem with my Embedded Derby DB. Been Stuck for hours. Can you see why?

When I Open my application, then do a function inserting a new rows in the database, my primary key starts with 1, 2, 3 and so forth.

But if I close the application and then open it, and do the same function inserting new rows, my primary key starts with with number basing on the next 100. the 1st time I reopen it, it will be 101,102, 103 and so on. The 2nd time i reuse my application, it will be 201, 202, 203...

**The table sql creation is below. Does not matter if I remove (increment by 1) or add (start with 1) in that column**

```
public static final String CREATE_TBL = "CREATE TABLE MyGamez.Game "
            + "(GameID INT not null primary key GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY"
            + "(Increment by 1), Title VARCHAR (40), Genre VARCHAR (30), Developer VARCHAR(30))";
```

**The resulting table with rows is this: every +100 is a new reopen of my application.**

```
GAMEID  TITLE   GENRE   DEVELOPER
1   a   a   a
2   aa  aa  aa
3   a   a   a
4   aaa a   a
101 a       
102 a   a   a
103 bb  b   b
201 asdasd  fasfs   fasfasf
301 fsdfd   ff  fff
302 ewew    ewewe   ewew
303 xxx xxx xxx
```

I am thinking just creating my own key, I just want it to be clean as possible. I came from MySQL, never had this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any OR mapper to access your tables?

Comment: I think Derby uses sequence cache for each session like many other DBs by default (for performance issues because each session can work with the same sequence generator). Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227697/sequences-current-value-advances-to-next-100-upon-reconnection-in-derby

Comment: @UwePlonus - No, i dont even know it until now. LOL.

Comment: @Multisync - Thanks for the link, I will try this, i was searching the net for this for hours. Will comeback.

Comment: @Multisync - sorry for late reply. It works. Thanks!

Comment: Note that GENERATED ... AS IDENTITY columns used to use a counter in SYSCOLUMNS, but were changed to use a SEQUENCE in Derby 10.11 as part of DERBY-6542: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-6542