# Java Derby database serial increments the wrong number

Tags: java, derby

I'm using an embedded Derby database in my project.

Here's my code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Derby {
    private static String query;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        String MEH = "jdbc:derby:zadb;create=true";
        Connection connection = connection = DriverManager.getConnection(MEH);
        query = "CREATE TABLE verduras(" +
                "id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) PRIMARY KEY," +
                "nombre varchar(20))";
        //connection.createStatement().executeUpdate(query);
        query = "INSERT into verduras (nombre)" +
                "VALUES ('pimiento')";
        connection.createStatement().executeUpdate(query);
        query = "INSERT into verduras (nombre)" +
                "VALUES ('tomate')";
        connection.createStatement().executeUpdate(query);
        query = "SELECT * FROM verduras";
        ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
        while (resultSet.next()){
            System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(1)+" - "+resultSet.getString(2));
        }
        connection.close();

    }
}
```

The problem is that the id doesn't increase 1 by 1 , when I reload the project the first insert increase the id by 100, any idea why it happens and how to correct it?

Comment: you have a syntax error at `Connection connection = connection = DriverManager.getConnection(MEH);`

Comment: sorry, that is a (probable) typographical error, not a syntax error

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227697/sequences-current-value-advances-to-next-100-upon-reconnection-in-derby