# trouble getting correct next value for sequence in derby 10.13.1.1

Tags: derby

I have a table admin.hibernate_sequence .
In next_val I have 5008 .

Making: `values next value for admin.hibernate_sequence`
I get: 408 .

Making: `select * from admin.hibernate_sequence`
I  get: 5008 .

Checking SYSSEQUENCES, there is a sequence named "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" with current value 508 .

calling again `values next value for admin.hibernate_sequence`, I get un incremented value, 409, but in any sequence/table I can't find any change.

I've tried to restart server, reconnect.

How can I sync "values next value for admin.hibernate_sequence" and "next_val" value from "admin.hibernate_sequence"

I've tried to search through tables for the value returned by the "next value for" expression but I can't find it.
I've read posts related to "next value for" expression, but none seem to explain where the number is coming from.
like in post [Sequence's current value advances to next 100 upon reconnection in derby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227697/sequences-current-value-advances-to-next-100-upon-reconnection-in-derby)